# How can I fetch document then save input to reference document with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am stuck at the moment as I am trying to find out how can I post new comments into the books schema.

My books schema is referencing the comments and I already have a post route to add a new book but I need a post route to add new comment to a specific book by ID. 
All examples I find here is creating a new schema for the book but I need to fetch the correct book document already created by it's id then store the new comment.

This is my schema for the book and the comment.

```
 var BookSchema = new Schema({
            title    : { type: String, required: true },
          commentcount    : Number,
          comments : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]

        mongoose.model( 'Book', BookSchema );

        var CommentSchema = new Schema({
            book   : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Book' }],
            comment    : { type: String, required: true },
        });

        mongoose.model( 'Comment', CommentSchema );
```

This is my post route where I am attempting to store new comment.

```
    .post(function(req, res){
          var bookid = req.params.id;
          var comment = req.body.comment;

        var newcomment = new Comment({name: comment, book: bookid});

        Book.findById(bookid, function(err, doc){

        doc.comments.push(newcomment);
        doc.commentcount += 1;
          console.log(doc);    
        doc.save(function(err) {
        // todo
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewriting your post function so that you can create the comment first, push the new comment id as an update on the `Book` model as follows:

```
.post(function(req, res){
    var bookid = req.params.id;
    var newComment = new Comment({
        name: req.body.comment,
        book: bookid
    });

    newComment.save().then(function(comment){
        Book.findByIdAndUpdate(
            bookid,
            { 
                "$push": { "comments": comment._id },
                "$inc": { "commentcount": 1 }
            },
            { "new": true, "upsert": true }
        ).exec();
    })
    .then(function(book) { res.send(book); })
    .catch(function(err) { throw err; });
});
```